I am not getting OTP and when i am getting some error i mentioned below
Where i am doing mistake hereenter image description here
Here I am getting successful message but i am not getting otp to my mobile number
`import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
RecaptchaVerifier,
signInWithPhoneNumber,
PhoneAuthProvider,
signInWithCredential,
} from "firebase/auth";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import OtpInput from "react-otp-input";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";
import { auth } from "../firebase/setup";

const OTPLogin = () => {
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
const [otp, setOtp] = useState("");
const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState("");
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const recaptchaRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
if (recaptchaRef.current && !window.recaptchaVerifier) {
 window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
 auth,
  recaptchaRef.current,
  {
      size: "invisible",
      callback: (response) => {
        console.log("reCAPTCHA solved");
      },
      "expired-callback": () => {
        console.log("reCAPTCHA expired");
      },
    }
  );

  // Render reCAPTCHA
  window.recaptchaVerifier
    .render()
    .catch((err) => console.error("Error rendering reCAPTCHA:", err));
   }
}, []);

const sendOtp = async () => {
setIsLoading(true);
try {
  const formattedPhoneNumber = `+${phoneNumber}`;  
 formatted
  if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
    throw new Error("reCAPTCHA verifier not initialized");
  }
  console.log(formattedPhoneNumber);
  const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
  const confirmationResult = await signInWithPhoneNumber(
    auth,
    formattedPhoneNumber,
    appVerifier
  );
  window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
  setVerificationId(confirmationResult.verificationId);
  console.log(confirmationResult);
  setIsLoading(false);
  console.log(`OTP sent successfully to ${phoneNumber}`);

} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error sending OTP:", error);
  setError(error.message);
  setIsLoading(false);
}
  };

 const verifyOtp = async () => {
 setIsLoading(true);
  try {
  if (!verificationId) {
    throw new Error("Verification ID is not set");
  }

  const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, otp);
  await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
  toast.success("Logged in successfully");
  setError(""); // Clear any previous error
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error verifying OTP:", error);
  setError(error.message);
  }
  setIsLoading(false);
};

 return (
 <div >
  <h1>Login with OTP</h1>
  <div ref={recaptchaRef} id="recaptcha-container"></div>
  <div>
    <PhoneInput
      country={"in"}
      value={phoneNumber}
      onChange={setPhoneNumber}
    />
  </div>
  <button onClick={sendOtp}>Submit</button>
  <div>
    <OtpInput
      value={otp}
      onChange={setOtp}
      numInputs={6}
      shouldAutoFocus
      renderInput={(props) => <input {...props} />}
      inputStyle={{
        width: "50px",
        height: "50px",
        margin: "0 5px",
        outline: "none",
        border: "1px solid #000",
        fontSize: "16px",
        borderRadius: "8px",
        background: "transparent",
        color: "#000",
      }}
    />
  </div>
  {error && <p>{error}</p>}
 </div>
);
};

 export default OTPLogin;


import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
appId: "",
 };


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const auth = getAuth(app);`your text`

export { auth };`


please do not use images to include code or error messages in your question. Instead, put them in a code block inside the question text.
